# Fetch value from previous row and concatenate if condition is met in R

Tags: r, concatenation, conditional-statements

I want to fetch string from previous row and concatenate with current row string if condition is met from another column

**Condition**: If 'Flag' is 1 then concatenate after fetching string from previous row in column AG and the current row string from columns AG.

My data frame sample is given below this and the desired result is given in "Desired result" column

```
AG       Flag   Desired result
Team a   0  
Team b   0  
CI       0  
Team a   1      CI to Team a
Team b   0  
Team b   0  
C        0  
CI       1      C to CI
Team a   0  
Team b   1      Team a to Team b
```

and my code is

```
mydata$trans <- ifelse(mydata$Flag == 1,paste(mydata$AG[-1],"to",mydata$AG[-nrow(mydata)]),"")
```

I got the following result:

```
AG       Flag   trans
Team a   0  
Team b   0  
CI       0  
Team a   1      Team b to Team a
Team b   0  
Team b   0  
C        0  
CI       1      Team a to CI
Team a   0  
Team b   0 
C        0      
CI       1      Team a to CI
Team a   0      
Team b   1      Team b to Team a
```

I realised my code is wrong but I'm not able to find out solution even after many trial and error.
Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using the `?lag` function from package `dplyr` (I also use `with` to reduce typing `mydata` several times and reduce the logical test to only `Flag` because 0 and 1 are automatically interpreted as logical values):

```
require(dplyr)
mydata$trans <- with(mydata, ifelse(Flag, paste(dplyr::lag(AG,1), "to", AG), ""))
#mydata
#       AG Flag            trans
#1  Team_a    0                 
#2  Team_b    0                 
#3      CI    0                 
#4  Team_a    1     CI to Team_a
#5  Team_b    0                 
#6  Team_b    0                 
#7       C    0                 
#8      CI    1          C to CI
#9  Team_a    0                 
#10 Team_b    1 Team_a to Team_b
```

You could leave out the `dplyr::` but I leave it there so it's not confused with `stats::lag`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a for loop that does what you want, assuming your table is called `x`.

```
x$trans <- NA
for (i in 2:nrow(x)) {
   if (x[i, 2] == 1) {
      x[i, 3] <- paste(x[i - 1, 1], "to", x[i, 1])
   }
}
```

I start the loop at the second index, because I'm not sure how you want to handle the case where `Flag` is 1 on the first row. You could easily handle that special case alone or maybe even modify the loop.

Comment: The 1st row would never be 1 in my data. I would be using the for a huge dataset (1 million rows) Is for loop recommended in this case? Thanks !

Comment: You might be better off with the solution that @beggineR posted. It looks like a nice vectorized approach.